# LVL crashes on Jelly Bean

Tags: java, android, android-lvl

On Android documentation is written I can ask here about LVL problems.

My Android LVL was working great on android <=4.0.4 . 
Today I updated to Jelly Bean and it doesn't work anymore. Here is the logcat:

```
07-27 19:53:28.036: I/Spegni schermo intelligente PRO(2976): Lo schermo si è acceso
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087): Activity it.android.smartscreenoffpro.LicenseCheck has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker@41754650 that was originally bound here
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity it.android.smartscreenoffpro.LicenseCheck has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker@41754650 that was originally bound here
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:965)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:859)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1191)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1183)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:394)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker.checkAccess(LicenseChecker.java:150)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at it.android.smartscreenoffpro.LicenseCheck.doCheck(LicenseCheck.java:89)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at it.android.smartscreenoffpro.LicenseCheck.onCreate(LicenseCheck.java:106)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Must I update something?

Comment: As far as i can see you need to check the following line: 
07-27 19:53:34.661: E/ActivityThread(3087):     at it.android.smartscreenoffpro.LicenseCheck.doCheck(LicenseCheck.java:89)

TL:DR: Line 89

Comment: Line 89: private void doCheck() {
  mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
 }

Comment: I don't think publishing the entire package is a good idea since is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found the solution (explanation):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=26722

This is an issue.